# Access Child class method from Base class Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have one base class

```
class C1 extends C {

}
```

and I have one derived class

```
class C2 extends C1 {
    public void init() {

    }
}
```

My program starts with the class C1 and how should I call 'init()' method of C2?

Comment: did you mean `C2 c2 = new C2(); c2.init();`

Comment: No idea what you are asking for. The question title and the question body are somehow not really related.

Comment: The whole point of inheritance is that C1 does not know the specifics of C2. What you can do is make an abstract method init in C1, this way it's no longer specific to C2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick to call a method of `derived` class from its `parent` class:

```
public class Parent {

    public Parent() {
        speak(); // call private methods in constructor if you need
    }

    void speak() {
        System.out.println("Parent speak implementation");
    }
}   

public class Child extends Parent {

    public Child() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    void speak() {
        System.out.println("Child speak implementation");
    }
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent c = new Child();
    }   
}
```

But it is **not recommended** and you should **avoid it**! The right way to do it is just declare `init()` method in your `super class, C1` and `override` it in your `derived class, C2` and call it as follow:

```
C1 c1 = new C2();
c1.init(); // will be called init method of C2 class
```

I see that you are extending from `Activity` class and I assume that this is from `Android`. If it is so I would recommend you to try to do as follow:

```
public abstract class C1 extends Activity {
    protected abstract void init();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c1);

        // your logic
    }
}

public class C2 extends C1 {

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

And in your manifest file declare your `main activity` as follow:

```
<activity android:name=".C2">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you would like to access class `C2` by instantiating an object of class `C1`, you cannot do so, due to inheritance rules.
**Edit:** I can give you a concrete example: a Car is a subclass of a Vehicle, so when you create the Vehicle class, you cannot have a Car yet, because it depends on the existence of a Vehicle.
So, in your case, as the class `C2` depends on the existence of class `C1`, you cannot call methods of class `C2` from class `C1`.
I believe that it is important that you get the full concept of inheritance in order to understand how OOP works, so I suggest you to have a look at [this book](https://www.bluej.org/objects-first/description.html) that explains well this concepts.

Comment: Is it possible with any other methods like adding interface? Object instance must only from C1.

Comment: It is possible only if C2 does not extend C1. Or do what @valentin-waeselynck pointed out.